# Random variables can only lose mass in the limit

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $X$ be a random variable and $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of uniformly bounded random variables in $L^1$, meaning $\exists C>0 \colon\mathbb{E}[|X_n|]<C,\ \forall n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Furthermore, let $X_n\rightarrow X$ almost surely. By Fatou's Theorem 
$$
\mathbb{E}[|X|]\le \liminf_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{E}[|X_n|]\le C, \ C\in \mathbb{R}^+
$$

This was justified by "Random variables can only lose mass in the limit". I don't understand the last inequality, since this is surely not in general the case. Take $f_n=1_{[-n,n]}$, then $f_n\in L^1(\lambda)$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, but the limit is not.

What I can think of is using the Portmanteau Lemma, which gives an equivalent characterization for weak convergence, which is that for an open $A$
$$\liminf_{n\to\infty}\mu_n(A)\ge\mu(A) $$
Since convergence a.s. implies weak convergence, the lemma could be applied. But I don't see how.

Comment: Are you asking why $\liminf_{n\to\infty} \mathbb{E}[|X_n|]\leq C$ for some $C\in \mathbb{R}^+$?

Comment: Usually, being uniformly bounded in $L^1$ means that $\sup_n ||X_n||_{L^1} <\infty,$ which is stronger than the $\mathbb{E} |X_n|<\infty \forall n\in\mathbb{N}$ that you require.

Comment: Remember that  $P(\Omega) = 1$ for a probability space, so in your example the limit would be in $L^1$ because every constant function is integrable with respect to every probability measure.

Comment: @Dasherman I made an edit!